# LXQt - stop screen-locking upon waking from suspend/sleep

Tags: screen-lock, lxqt

***Posted in order to provide the answer.***

---

I have a good experience with LXQt desktop environment installed on top of Kubuntu 18.04, but it still has some odd features - about which it is not that easy as for other desktops to gather information on the internet.

- When waking from suspend an odd message appears saying *"xscreensaver not installed or not working"* - and I cannot get rid of it (I can dismiss it but it comes back next time).
- Installing xscreensaver, it locks the screen and asks for password when waking the system from sleep state.

How to stop screen-locking upon suspend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in the case described above `xscreensaver` was used as a screen locker.

If a screen locker is not installed, the system asks for it - unless screen locking is disabled from *LXQt > Preferences > LXQt Settings > Session Settings > Lock screen before suspending/hibernating* - by un-checking the box there.

[image]

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXQt